# VestaCP - Redirect subdomain to port on my server

Tags: apache, redirect, subdomain, virtualhost, vesta

I've been struggling with these for years... then I quit and now I want to do it again.

I have a DigitalOcean doplet with VestaCP installed on it and a few websites/users.

One of those websites is mine (let's name it *mycoolapp.com*) and I'm using it to display a web page and a web app (Spring Boot)

The app runs on a certain port, lest say *1234* and I wan't to link it to a subdomain on my site.

Here's what I done:

- Create a CNAME record that points app.mycoolapp.com as an alias of mycoolapp.com
- Then I try with htaccess:

```html
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^app.mycoolapp.com $ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mycoolapp.com:1234$1 [R=301,L]
```

but it's not working

- Also try modifying **/home/$USER/conf/web/apache2.conf** adding at the end of it:

```html
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName app.mycoolapp.com
    redirect / http://mycoolapp.com:1234/
</VirtualHost>
```

And still not working.

In both cases, what I see is that whenever I enter app.mycoolapp.com I go to my admin web page (the same page I would see if I paste the droplet IP in my browser). And this is happening ever since I create the CNAME record

Comment: The app is working itself? You can access it via mycoolapp.com:1234?

Comment: Yes it is! I've been told that it is highly possible that I can not do what I want with VestaCP.

Comment: But .htaccess are generelly working?

Comment: I try it but it did not work... I will look for the post where they told me that it is not possible with Vesta so you can take a look at it